# Prove by induction that (5^(n))-1 is divisible by 4 for all natural numbers n.

Tags: induction, exponential-function

Prove by induction that $5^n-1$ is divisible by $4$ for all natural numbers $n$.

I got $P(k+1)=5^{k+1}-1$ but I don't where to go now.

Comment: *Hint* Use that $x^{n+1}-1=(x-1)(1+x+\cdots+x^n)$.

Comment: Or alternatively, $5^{k+1}-1 = 5\times 5^k - 1 = 4\times 5^k + 5^k - 1$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that $5^{k+1}-1=5(5^k-1)+4$. Now use your induction assumption that says $4|5^k-1$.

Comment: Not familiar with the notation at the end.

Comment: $4 \mid 5^{k}-1$ reads "$4$ divides $5^{k} -1$".

Comment: Yes, exactly. For all integers $a,b$, the notation $a|b$ means $a$ divides $b$ or $a$ is a factor $b$ or $b$ is divisible by $a$ or $b$ is a multiple of $a$.

Answer (score 5):

Although induction is required, perhaps you might also be interested in a non-inductive proof.  Since $5 \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$, then $5^k \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

And so we have $5^n - 1 \equiv (1-1) \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$.  We conclude that $4|(5^n - 1)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I don't understand what warrants the downvote.  Sure, I didn't answer the question precisely to OP's standards, but it's often enlightening to see things proven in more than one way.  Further, my proof can actually be tinkered with to yield an (albeit silly) inductive proof.  Why limit one's education to the arbitrary guidelines on some intro-to-proofs homework?

Comment: Yup, this doesn't deserve a downvote. +1 from me here (it was my first thought).

Answer (score 2):

$5^{k+1}-1=(5^{k}-1)\cdot 5+4$

If $5^{k}-1$ is divisible by 4, what can you say about this expression?